# Why can't I call hash() on an apparently hashable method of an unhashable instance?

Tags: python, dictionary, methods, instance, hashable

Let's say I have a dictionary:

```
>>> d = {}
```

It has a method `clear()`:

```
>>> d.clear
<built-in method clear of dict object at 0x7f209051c988>
```

... which has a `__hash__` attribute:

```
>>> d.clear.__hash__
<method-wrapper '__hash__' of builtin_function_or_method object at 0x7f2090456288>
```

... which is callable:

```
>>> callable(d.clear.__hash__)
True
```

So why can't I hash it?

```
>>> hash(d.clear)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict'
```

**Note:** I know that `dict` objects are unhashable – I'm curious as to why this restriction extends to their methods, even though, as noted above, they appear to claim otherwise?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

It is a bound method, and bound methods have a reference to `self`, e.g. the dictionary. This makes the method un-hashable.

You *can* hash the unbound `dict.clear` method:

```
>>> d = {}
>>> d.clear.__self__
{}
>>> d.clear.__self__ is d
True
>>> hash(d.clear)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict'
>>> hash(dict.clear)
-9223372036586189204
```

Methods on instances that *are* hashable will themselves be hashable, so the object type for built-in bound methods implements a `__hash__` method but raises `TypeError` when the `__self__` attribute is not hashable. This is consistent with the `object.__hash__` method documentation; if you can set it to `None` or not implement it at all then that is preferable but for these cases where the hashability is only known at runtime raising a `TypeError` is the only option available.

Answer (score 11):

Martijn is right as he very often is. If you have a `dict` subclass that does implement the `__hash__` method, even the bound methods become hashable

```
class MyHashableDict(dict):
    def __hash__(self):
        return 42

x = MyHashableDict()
print(x, hash(x), hash(x.clear))

y = {}
print(y, hash(y.clear))
```

Output:

```
{} 42 287254
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "y.py", line 9, in <module>
    print(hash(y.clear))
TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict'
```